# Insert a nested object in Firebase

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

Been stuck on this problem for a while, so what I want to do is this:
When I create a form, write the form to the database along with a list of users, along with their email addresses - like this:

formsById -> formId -> userId (contains the users email address)

I can then filter all of the forms by the current user like this:

```
  getFormList() {
    return firebase.database().ref('/formsByID').orderByChild('userList').startAt(this.userId).endAt(this.userId);
  }
```

Here is how I currently write to the database:

```
writeNewForm(formName: string, formDate: string): Promise<any> {

    // A post entry.
    let postData = {
      name: formName,
      date: formDate,
      userList: this.userId // I want to nest the email in here
    };

    // Get a key for a new Post.
    let newPostKey:string = this.formListRef.push().key;

    // Write the new post's data simultaneously in the posts list and the user's post list.
    let updates = {};
    // write to the users record
    updates[this.userPath + '/' + newPostKey] = true; // just set this to true be
    updates[this.formsByIdPath + '/' + newPostKey] = postData;

    return this.rootRef.update(updates);
    //return rootRef.update(updates);

  }
```

But I dont know how to nest my users email address under their id.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to modify your post entry to this:

```
// A post entry.
let postData = {
  name: formName,
  date: formDate,
  userList: [
    {email: this.userId} // I want to nest the email in here
  ]
};
```

or create an array of values:

```
// A post entry.
let postData = {
  name: formName,
  date: formDate,
  userList: [
    this.userId // I want to nest the email in here
  ]
};
```

then you can do a deep-path update.

Here you can find some more info:
https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/09/introducing-multi-location-updates-and_86.html